# Merging multiple Rows in ssrs report to a single one

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

[image]

I need help regarding SSRS Reporting my data is Coming from a Query and I also have added the Column Group Named as Subject Name Showing on the top of the Table() Also Added ApplicantID as Row Group and FName as a Row Group in the Report to fulfill my requirement that was just to show 
Since I am not Sure how many subjects a user can select its all decide on the run time so i did added the Subject name as a column group
All the Subject records in a single row for a specific ApplicantId Instead of showing below my Requirement is

It Should looks like as a table
 
                                  `Anatomy   Surgery  Zoology
                                  Part ISt`

`14   Hanan Qureshi  Iqbal Qureshi  15.00    20.00    10.00 
15    Tasneem Alam   Imtiaz Alam    30.00    10.00    20.00`

etc instead of Showing in a seperate row it should show in a single row
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your matrix that will show groups layout information?

Comment: I guess you have 1 detail row group, which you have to delete it and put sum(Odtained Marks).. this should resolve your issue...

Comment: @Aftab how can i add Screenshot(picture)  via comment ???

Comment: Aftab i have added in the original question u can see it dear

Comment: hemanth i think ur not getting my point i just want to display multiple records as one against a specific ID

Comment: You can edit your current post and add additional picture

Comment: @Aftab i have already done it please check the picture on the top

Comment: I think, remove obtained marks grouping from row group. After this, you should be fine

Comment: @Usama i guess you were doing row parent grouping by Applicant ID.. if so you will find a parent group and a detail group(with symbol as 3 horizontal lines), you can see at the bottom when table is selected. you need to delete that detail...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Details group is your problem as @hemanth said you need to remove this and add in an aggregate function (max, min, sum, average) any will work since there is only one value for each SubjectName, Obtained Mark Combo. this will give you all the marks on one line for each applicant.