# SSRS Row Grouping help needed please

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I'm guessing this is very simple but I am missing something and need help please.

My dataset looks like:

```
 CITY         STREET      HOUSES
 Norton       Main St     10
 Newton       Main St     30
 Providence   Angel St    15
 Boston       State St    50
```

I created a row group which groups by Street, but I am still getting 2 rows broken down by HOUSE numbers.  Like this

```
 STREET        HOUSES
 Main St       10
               30
 Angel St      15
 State St      50
```

How do I SUM(HOUSES) based on the STREET column? I want my output to look like this (using SSRS grouping not SQL)

```
 STREET        HOUSES
 Main St       40
 Angel St      15
 State St      50
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have a details group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the details group and enter your aggregate expression `Sum(Houses)` into the cell. this will then group on street as you are expecting and not return each row from the dataset.

its not  completely unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907318/merging-multiple-rows-in-ssrs-report-to-a-single-one/25912141#25912141) question, but this one also had column groups.

Comment: Thank you! This worked and allowed me to sum the 2 rows properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by street, once you have that you will have the same data that you have right now. what you need to do next is right click on houses, add new row outside the group, and in one of those cells place SUM(HOUSES) (so inside the street group). once you have that you can delete your old row and play around with that.
hope this helps, cheers.